# Adding spring-cloud-starter-sleuth dependency to a Spring-Boot App some of the Rest Doc test failing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflow, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-restdocs

I have a Spring-Boot 2.1.4 application with n-RestDoc tests for Flux controller.

Environment:

- Spring-Boot 2.1.4
- Junit 5.4.0
- spring-restdocs-webtestclient
- spring-webflux

If I add the spring-clout-starter-sleuth dependendcy to the app, some of the doc test fails in maven build. 
Important on different environment different test classes fails with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext@6516dd09 has been closed already ....
```

If run the failling test with maven `-Dtest=OptDocTest` than the test will not fail, also if a set (not all) test where specified.

Dependendcy

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
     <exclusions> <!-- exclude old spring versions -->
          <exclusion>
               <artifactId>*</artifactId>
               <groupId> org.springframework.security</groupId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

All test looks simular

```
@ExtendWith({ RestDocumentationExtension.class, SpringExtension.class })
@AutoConfigureRestDocs("target/generated-snippets")
@SpringBootTest(//webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, 
        classes = { ArchimedesApplication.class })
class OptControllerDocTest {

   @MockBean
   private SrkConnector srkTConnector;

   @Autowired
   private ApplicationContext context;

   private WebTestClient webTestClient;

   @BeforeEach
   void beforeEach(RestDocumentationContextProvider restDocumentation) {
        this.webTestClient = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(context)
              .configureClient() 
              .filter(documentationConfiguration(restDocumentation))
              .build();

   }

   @Test
   void documentationTest() throws IOException {

        this.webTestClient.post()
            .uri("/opt")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(testRequest))
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus()  // here the error occur
            .isOk()
            .expectBody() ...
    }
```

All IT Test with a running Boot Application works correct.

I have no idea what goes wrong and why the `AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext` is closed.

On a windows box the rest doc test for controller with a flux content fails on a linux box for controller with mono content.

Comment: Why do you exclude Spring versions from the Sleuth dependency?

Comment: Very easy - I have Spring Boot 2.1.4 and spring-framework 5.1.6
and started with sleuth version 2.1.0 and this had different versions so I had a spring version mix.

Comment: Info: same behaviour if I remove all exclusion from the sleuth dependency

Comment: Why do you alter the spring versions at all? It should come from Boot. Also it would be good to have the full stacktrace or any additional pieces of information cause currently I don't know how to help you

Comment: ```spring-cloud-starter-sleuth``` come from springframework.cloud and have own dependency and is not part of spring-boot, but it make no differrence because without exclusions the same error occures.

Answer (score 1):

It is solved if I fall back to `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` in version 2.1.0.RELEASE and remove all exclusions.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

If I use version 2.1.1.RELEASE the error occur.

Comment: And this does not seem to have been solved in 2.1.3-RELEASE either

Answer (score 1):

This has been raised as a bug in the sleuth github issue list [github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/1450](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/1450)

If you, as me, have had this situation in regard to junit tests, then I solved it by removing all annotations `@DirtiesContext` in every junit test class I had in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue I also met. I solved the issue by downgrade Sleuth to `2.0.3.RELEASE`(2.1.0 also not work with me). Mine Spring Boot version is `2.0.5.RELEASE`.
If 2.0.3 still not work for you, try more downgrade version from [mvn repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-sleuth)